# How to handle errors from Quickblox iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, error-handling, quickblox

I got this message from quickblox ios sdk,

```
{
    errors =     {
        email =         (
            "has already been taken"
        );
    };
}
```

I'm not sure how to handle error with quickblox? Is there a list of error messages that I can by forget the issue? I got to print this message with help of `QBResponse` object like this,

```
NSLog(@"%@",response.error.reasons);
```

Here reason is a `NSDictionary`, how do I know which error message key is inside?

At the same time, I got this message Expected status code in (200-299), got 422 for `NSLog(@"%@",response.error.error.localizedDescription);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check *localizedRecoverySuggestion* at first, if *nil* is there, than you should look for *reasons* dictionary. Unfortunately there are no standard keys that you could expect.